# SqPlus Linking Error?

Tags: c++, binding, linker

I am binding sqplus in my app. And having a undefined refference error. Here is the error -

> obj\Debug\CApp.o:c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/sqplus/SqPlusCallTemplates.h:106: undefined reference to `char* SqPlus::Get(SqPlus::TypeWrapper, SQVM*, int)'

Could some one kindly tell what I am missing. I am using C::B ide and I have linked all required libs in linker setting. The code is here -

```
// SQUIRREL
SquirrelVM::Init();

sq_setprintfunc(SquirrelVM::GetVMPtr(), CApp::PrintFunc);

SquirrelObject MainNut = SquirrelVM::CompileScript("main.nut");

try
 {
     SquirrelVM::RunScript(MainNut); // run the script
 }
 catch(SquirrelError & e)
 {
     // catch exceptions and print them out through the custom print function
     sq_getprintfunc(SquirrelVM::GetVMPtr())
        (SquirrelVM::GetVMPtr(),_SC("Error: %s, %s\n"),e.desc);
 }

// Bind the Image class
SQClassDef<CImage>(_SC("Image")).
    func(&CImage::NewImage,_SC("NewImage")).
    func(&CImage::SetPosition,_SC("SetPosition"));

CImage *Image = new CImage();

SquirrelFunction<void>(_SC("Init"))(Image);

SquirrelVM::Shutdown();
```

EDIT: libsquirrel.a, libsqstd.a and libsqplus.a in project menu -> project build options -> linker settings tab. It is SQUIRREL2_1_1.

Thanks in advance.
  Regards.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the full linker settings?

Answer (score 0):

This function: `char* SqPlus::Get(SqPlus::TypeWrapper, SQVM*, int)` has a prototype, but no implementation.

Comment: How do I get rid of it? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It is not possible to comment out that line. If I do so, I get bunch of error - no matching function call or too few argument.

Comment: I think the problem was this - SquirrelFunction<void>(_SC("Init"))(Image);. I am not getting the errors any more but nothing is happening. Here is the zip file - http://www.mediafire.com/?6103bjcca7fu5y5.